# Keyless Contracts?

Tags: keys

What is a keyless contract and how do you achieve this?

this is a keyless contract:
https://github.com/NedAmarril/eosiopowcoin
in bloks.io i can see that it has eosio.prod active keys...but what does that mean? and is it possible for anyone to modify it after it has been deployed?
https://bloks.io/account/eosiopowcoin#keys

I have a contract that would benefit from keyless transactions, in the sense that my users can trust the contract owner or a compromised key can't fiddle with the contract dynamics I have set up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keys of eosio.prod means it needs 15/21 Block Producers to modify the contract. (see eosio.token for example)